# MAMP icon unresponsive, unable to open

Tags: wordpress, apache, mamp

I have just installed MAMP in Windows 10 alongside my class so that we can begin to work with Wordpress. However, the installed icon, and the app itself within my 'start' search function is unresponsive. I always get this popup: "To run this application, you must install .NET Core." The Popup has MAMP.exe in the corner. I did the recommended download at x64, and got confirmation that it was installed, but I got no result. Any time I try to click on the MAMP icon on my desktop, I get that message. I made sure my Skype was off, I checked if I had multiple Apache installations (I saw none except a years-old one in an archived folder) and I restarted my computer but to no avail. I wonder if there is an issue with the path or the browser -- .NET Core was done with Edge, MAMP was done with Chrome. This is mysterious. If anyone has advice on what to try, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! Download x86 version of .NET Core and then install it afterward no matter how old your computer is. I did that and it works perfectly now.